# Windows 8 start menu tile labels disappeared

Tags: windows-8, graphics-card, 64-bit, start-menu, tiles

I had Windows 8 32 bit, when I installed Windows 8 64 bit, this happened! The labels from the start menu tiles disappeared! I have installed the latest graphic card driver for 64 bit from nVidia. But this is still happening. I have i3-2100 @ 3.1 GHz. 4 gb ram and nVidia GTX 630 2gb ram grapchic card with latest 64 bit driver installed. See the image, it shows exactly what has happened and can anyone please suggest something?

[image: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/99185097/dont_delete_2.png]

Comment: disable the FXAA setting in the nVIDIA control panel. Does this help?

Comment: Didn't Help! @magicandre1981

Comment: you use Win8 (6.2)? Try Windows 8.1 (go to the store and upgrade to 8.1). Do you still have this here? Also try different driver versions.